# Android startBluetoothSco doesn't work 5.0.2

Tags: android, bluetooth

Called 'startBluetoothSco()' work for android 4.4

Just record to bluetooth headset microphone.

When record start called
  audioManager.startBluetoothSco();

record ended
  audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();

I did try to setMode (Communication, Call) but doesn't work in Android 5.0.2

Forget what I'm in?

Thanks.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=156264
I found this issue thread.

Comment: If this problem, just android api bug...?